# Handle Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a fairly simple query which uses the `Substring` function to extract information from a description. However, some descriptions are exceptionally formatted, causing the error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I would like to, in the case the Substring function fails, return the entire description instead. Searching for a solution online, however, did not get me anywhere. The `TRY...CATCH` construct seems useful, but I cannot figure out how to use it in this instance.

```
Select 
    ST.Description
    , SUBSTRING(ST.Description, PATINDEX('% ([0-9]% x %) -%', ST.Description) + 2, CHARINDEX('x', SUBSTRING(ST.Description, PATINDEX('% ([0-9]% x %) -%', ST.Description) + 2, 20))-2) AS SubTaskQTY    
From astTaskSubTasks ST    
Join astTasks T ON T.Id = ST.ParentId
Join astAssets A ON A.Id = T.AssetId
Where A.Code = '2016100011'
```

Comment: Hi Tim, instead of catching errors you could use "case when" expression to avoid exceptions. Here the link to the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
ST.Description
, CASE PATINDEX('% ([0-9]% x %) -%', ST.Description) 
        WHEN 0 THEN ST.Description
        ELSE SUBSTRING(ST.Description, PATINDEX('% ([0-9]% x %) -%', ST.Description) + 2, CHARINDEX('x', SUBSTRING(ST.Description, PATINDEX('% ([0-9]% x %) -%', ST.Description) + 2, 20))-2)
    END
 AS SubTaskQTY

From astTaskSubTasks ST

Join astTasks T ON T.Id = ST.ParentId
Join astAssets A ON A.Id = T.AssetId

Where A.Code = '2016100011'


SELECT  PATINDEX('% ([0-9]% x %) -%', '1 x -')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this which allows you to test that the substring is going to work before attempting it.

```
select 
  ST.[Description]
  , case when FirstIndex > 2 and SecondIndex > 0
    then SUBSTRING(ST.[Description], FirstIndex, SecondIndex) else ST.[Description] end AS SubTaskQTY
from (
  select [Description]--, ParentId
    , PATINDEX('% ([0-9]% x %) -%', [Description]) + 2 FirstIndex
    , CHARINDEX('x', SUBSTRING([Description], PATINDEX('% ([0-9]% x %) -%', [Description]) + 2, 20)) - 2 SecondIndex
  from astTaskSubTasks
) ST
join astTasks T ON T.Id = ST.ParentId
join astAssets A ON A.Id = T.AssetId
where A.Code = '2016100011'
```

Comment: I don't quite follow this query, and it does not work. The same error persists, and I think this is because the 6th line is still trying to extract the information when it can't

Comment: @TimStack when working it does pretty much what the other answer does. Need some sample data to actually test it. Hopefully the principle shows you how to get it working.

Comment: I see your error now. You're checking for `>=2` which should be `>2`. If `FirstIndex` is 2, that would mean PATINDEX returned nothing, which is equal to an error.

Comment: Also please stop with the rather useless editing of my post

Comment: Good point, I never remember whether its 0 or 1 based for a match.

Comment: @TimStack if you read the editing guidelines questions should be concise and without *fluff*. It is encouraged to edit out *fluff* (its encouraged not to add it in the first place).

Comment: @TimStack https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: If you add `-2` to `SecondIndex` as per my query, I'll upvote your answer.